# Invalid identifier when comparing to string in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to teach myself SQL using the HackerRank challenges and I am currently trying to select the sum of the populations of all the specified cities that are within Asia.

The table structures are:

For the `City` table:

```
+-------------+----------+
| Field       | Type     |
+-------------+----------+
| ID          | int(11)  |
| Name        | char(35) |
| CountryCode | char(3)  |
| District    | char(20) |
| Population  | int(11)  |
+-------------+----------+
```

For the `Country` table:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| Field          | Type        |
+----------------+-------------+
| Code           | char(3)     |
| Name           | char(52)    |
| Continent      | char(50)    |
| Region         | char(26)    |
| SurfaceArea    | float(10,2) |
| IndepYear      | smallint(6) |
| Population     | int(11)     |
| LifeExpectancy | float(3,1)  |
| GNP            | float(10,2) |
| GNPOld         | float(10,2) |
| LocalName      | char(45)    |
| GovernmentForm | char(45)    |
| HeadOfState    | char(60)    |
| Capital        | int(11)     |
| Code2          | char(2)     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Population) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         City.Population AS Population, 
         Country.Continent AS Continent 
     FROM 
         City 
     INNER JOIN 
         Country ON City.CountryCode = Country.Code) 
WHERE 
    Continent = "Asia";
```

Which as far as I know should sum the populations of all cities whose country code is the same as a country who is in Asia. However, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "Asia": invalid identifier

Comment: Use `'Asia'`  instead of `"` use `'`

Comment: @lad2025 That worked, thanks; what is the use of double quotes `"` in SQL Server then?

Comment: If you're using **SQL Server** - why are you getting an `ORA-00904` error??

Comment: @Shaktal If you want to learn more about SQL Server you can use videolectures provided by [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developing-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Databases), they cover almost every topic, search for SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'Asia'` instead of `"Asia"`. **By default string literals** are enclosed with `'`.

You can use `"` in **table/object identifiers** like:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/219b0/2/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE "a c"(b iNT);

INSERT INTO "a c"(b)
VALUES (2), (3);

SELECT *
FROM "a c";
```

But you should use `[]` to quote db object names like:

```
CREATE TABLE [a c](b iNT);

INSERT INTO [a c](b)
VALUES (2), (3);

SELECT *
FROM [a c];
```

Be aware this will only work when [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)  is `ON`.

> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, identifiers can be delimited by double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single quotation marks

To use `""` as string literals use:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

SELECT SUM(Population) FROM 
   (SELECT City.Population AS Population, 
           Country.Continent AS Continent 
    FROM City INNER JOIN Country 
    ON City.CountryCode = Country.Code) 
WHERE Continent = "Asia";
```

Comment: I will be very happy to get more feedback why I've got downvote. So I can improve my answer.